# How to solve a problem 'router-outlet' is not a known element?

Tags: angular

I have app module and shared module. In app-routing module I have:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { SiteLayoutComponent } from "./shared/layouts/site-layout/site-layout.component";
import { LoginPageComponent } from "./components/login-page/login-page.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: SiteLayoutComponent,
    children:
      [{path: 'login', component: LoginPageComponent}]
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})

export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

In app.component.ts:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  template: '<router-outlet></router-outlet>'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'TheEda';
}
```

In shared module:

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

import { HeaderComponent } from './layouts/header/header.component';
import { SiteLayoutComponent } from './layouts/site-layout/site-layout.component';


@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    HeaderComponent,
    SiteLayoutComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
  ]
})
export class SharedModule { }
```

And also in shared module in site-layout component in site-layout.component.html:

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

I have an Error: src/app/shared/layouts/site-layout/site-layout.component.html:1:1 - error NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element.
How can this be fixed? What is missing in my code?

Comment: possible missing imports ... RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ... BrowserModule ... where routes might look like ... const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'main',
    loadChildren: () => import('./routes/main/main.module').then(m => m.MainModule)
  },
  {path: '**', redirectTo: '/main'}
]

Comment: it looks like your `AppRoutingModule` isn't included in the main one

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['router-outlet' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517737/router-outlet-is-not-a-known-element)

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your `AppRoutingModule` is missed to registered with `AppModule`.
Try to import `AppRoutingModule` to `AppModule` and see.

If you still see same issues then please try to share whole code on stack blitz.