# 'router-outlet' is not a known element Angular CLI: 13.3.5 Node: 16.15.0

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, angular-routing

I'm trying to use `<router-outlet>` but getting an error.

Error: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:

1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add `'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA'` to the `'@NgModule.schemas'` component to suppress this message.ng

*Angular CLI: 13.3.5
Node: 16.15.0
Package Manager: npm 8.18.0
Visual Studio Code Version: 1.70.2*

I checked many other similar questions on StackOverflow but my code seems right.

app.module.ts :

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http'
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { SearchBarComponent } from './components/search-bar/search-bar.component';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    SearchBarComponent,
    HomeComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    AppRoutingModule,
    BrowserModule,
    RouterModule,   
    HttpClientModule,      
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app-routing.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { HomeComponent } from './components/home/home.component';

const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path:'',
    component: HomeComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'search/:game-search',
    component: HomeComponent
  }

];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

app.component.html

```
<app-search-bar></app-search-bar>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['router-outlet' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517737/router-outlet-is-not-a-known-element)

Comment: your code seems correct. maybe some caching? have you tried to delete node modules and reinstalling?

Comment: No, i tried all solutions in this link. It didn't work.

Comment: I will try to re-install node modules

Comment: Note that you dont need to import `RouterModule` in `AppModule` since you are importing it and exporting it in `AppRoutingModule`. Then `AppModule` imports the `AppRoutingModule`. Maybe this is not a fix to your problem but is important to note.

Comment: I tried re-install node modules but it didn't work.

Comment: @Gly Could you try to replicate the issue in a stackblitz for angular13? maybe you will catch what is going wrong