# ERROR NG8001, router-outlet is not a known element

Tags: angular, router-outlet

None of the answers here solved the problem:['router-outlet' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517737/router-outlet-is-not-a-known-element)

[ERROR] NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element:

1. If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.
2. If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the '@NgModule.schemas' of this component to suppress this message. [plugin angular-compiler]

   src/app/app.component.html:336:0:
   336 │ 
   ╵ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

Error occurs in the template of component AppComponent.

```
src/app/app.component.ts:5:15:
  5 │   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    ╵                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Application bundle generation failed. [0.216 seconds]

Angular CLI: 17.0.6
Node: 18.16.0
Package Manager: npm 9.5.1
OS: win32 x64

app.module.ts

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { RouterModule} from '@angular/router';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';

    import { AppRoutingModule, routes } from './app.routes';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { DataBindingComponent } from './data-binding/data-binding.component';
    import { NgIfNgforComponent } from './ng-if-ngfor/ng-if-ngfor.component';
    import { HttpClient, HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';
    import { SegundoComponenteComponent } from './segundo-componente/segundo-componente.component';

    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        DataBindingComponent,
        AppComponent,
        SegundoComponenteComponent,
        NgIfNgforComponent
      ],

      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(routes),
        AppRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ],
      providers: [HttpClient],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }`
```

app.routes.ts

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { DataBindingComponent } from './data-binding/data-binding.component';
    import { SegundoComponenteComponent } from './segundo-componente/segundo-componente.component';
    import { NgIfNgforComponent } from './ng-if-ngfor/ng-if-ngfor.component';

    export const routes: Routes = [
        {path: 'primeiro-componente', component: DataBindingComponent},
        {path: 'segundo-componente', component: SegundoComponenteComponent},
        {path: 'teste', component: NgIfNgforComponent}
    ];

    @NgModule ({
        imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
        exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

app.component.ts

```js
    import { Component } from '@angular/core';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-root',
      templateUrl: './app.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'] // Corrigido aqui
    })
    export class AppComponent {
      title = 'cursoAngular';
    }
```

Comment: I found out what happens. Since Angular 17, the default is standalone mode. I didn't know that. So when I created my project I did with ng new nameProject, but it didn't create the app.module.ts. I created the app.module manually and that caused the bug. To create a module-based application in Angular 17, you need to use --no-standalone (ng new nameApp --no-standalone).

Answer (score 0):

I think you don't need `RouterModule.forRoot(routes)` in the imports in `app.module.ts`. You're already importing `AppRoutingModule` there which covers the `RouterModule` import.

So it would look like this in app.module.ts:

```js
imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        CommonModule,
        HttpClientModule
      ]
```

Comment: Restrain from answering such a trivial duplicate questions

Comment: None of the question here solved the problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517737/router-outlet-is-not-a-known-element