# Why 'router-outlet' is not a known element in Angular 17

Tags: angular, routes

I've just created a new angular project using the Angular 17:

If 'router-outlet' is an Angular component, then verify that it is part of this module.

If 'router-outlet' is a Web Component then add 'CUSTOM_ELEMENTS_SCHEMA' to the

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.css'
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'video-library';
}

import { ApplicationConfig } from '@angular/core';
import { provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

import { routes } from './app.routes';

export const appConfig: ApplicationConfig = {
  providers: [provideRouter(routes)]
};

import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

import { UserComponent } from './components/user/user.component';
import { MovieComponent } from './components/movie/movie.component';
import { RentalComponent } from './components/rental/rental.component';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
    { path: 'users', component: UserComponent },
    { path: 'movies', component: MovieComponent },
    { path: 'rentals', component: RentalComponent },
    { path: '', redirectTo: '/movies', pathMatch: 'full' }
];

@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        UserComponent,
        MovieComponent,
        RentalComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes)
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

import { Routes } from '@angular/router';
export const routes: Routes = [];

Comment: Please provide [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: When you were creating project, did you choose to add routing? Is `RouterModule` imported in your `AppModule`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ['router-outlet' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517737/router-outlet-is-not-a-known-element)

Comment: import { Routes } from '@angular/router';

export const routes: Routes = [];

Comment: If you're on a new angular 17 project it defaults to standalone application with no ngmodules. Whilst ngmodule's technically can interop with this architecture it's recommended to go fully standalone The docs are at angular.dev

Answer (score 0):

You can import `router-outlet` individually:

```
import { RouterOutlet } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet],
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrl: './app.component.scss',
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing `standalone` and `modular` approach, its an `either one of them` scenario, so fine tune your code so that you use any one of these approaches.

If you are going for a module approach, below is a stackblitz where angular is used using modules!

You are getting this error because you need to add `RouterModule` in the `imports` array of the `AppModule`!

```
@NgModule({
    declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        UserComponent,
        MovieComponent,
        RentalComponent
    ],
    imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes),
        RouterModule, // <- changed here!
    ],
    providers: [],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

[Stackblitz Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-vcq4pq?file=test%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp-routing.module.ts)

If you are going for standalone approach, please use the below approach where a stackblitz reference is attached.

Here too, we need to import the `RouterModule` to the imports array of the standalone component for routing features to work!

[stackblitz demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-uugjsa)

---

If that does not work out, try creating a new project using

For creating modular angular project

```
ng new test --standalone false --routing
```

for creating standalone angular project

```
ng new test
```

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment, here's a minimal standalone app with routing. No ngmodules

Standalone components import what they need directly.

### [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackblitz-starters-cufnpy?file=src%2Fmain.ts)

```
import 'zone.js';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { bootstrapApplication } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { RouterOutlet, RouterLink, provideRouter } from '@angular/router';

// app.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink],
  template: `

    <a routerLink='one'>Redirect to /one</a><br/>
    <a routerLink='two'>Redirect to /two </a><strong><-----------CLICK HERE</strong>

    <router-outlet/>
  `,
})
export class App {}

// e.g. one.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'one-comp',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `
    <h1>One component</h1>
  `,
})
export class OneComponent {}

// e.g. two.component.ts
@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  standalone: true,
  imports: [],
  template: `
    <h1>Two component</h1>
  `,
})
export class TwoComponent {}

// 2nd arg normally via app.config.ts
// bootstrapApplication in main.ts
bootstrapApplication(App, {
  providers: [
    provideRouter([
      { path: 'one', component: OneComponent },
      { path: 'two', component: TwoComponent },
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/one', pathMatch: 'full' },
    ]),
  ],
});
```