# NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element

Tags: routes, angular17

I have this issue: NG8001: 'router-outlet' is not a known element
I tried all options from this ['router-outlet' is not a known element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517737/router-outlet-is-not-a-known-element) but it doesn't work for me.

Angular CLI: 17.2.0

Node: 20.7.0

Package Manager: npm 10.4.0

OS: win32 ia32

app.module.ts

````
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import {AuthComponent} from "../components/auth/auth.component";
import {ReactiveFormsModule} from "@angular/forms";
import {RouterModule, Routes} from "@angular/router";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '/', component: AuthComponent },
]
// @ts-ignore
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    RouterModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot(Routes),
    AppComponent,
    AuthComponent

  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    ReactiveFormsModule,
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }```
````

Comment: `RouterModule` should not be in `declarations` - `RouterModule.forRoot(...)` should be moved to your `AppRoutingModule` - `AppRoutingModule` should export `RouterModule`

Comment: Thanks, this error has gone but I added  app-routing.module.ts

` import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import {AuthComponent} from "../components/auth/auth.component";

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'login', component: AuthComponent },
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [ RouterModule.forRoot(routes) ],
  exports: [ RouterModule ]
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}`

but I have empty page!