How to set up routes in angular
So i've been following along a tutorial for some basic angular stuff but i ran into a problem which i cant figure out.
The code i copied from the tutorial looks like this:
import {NgModule} from '@angular/core';
import { RouterModule, Routes } from '@angular/router';
import { BeszerzesEszkozSelectorComponent } from './components/pages/beszerzes-eszkoz-selector/beszerzes-eszkoz-selector.component';
import { LoginComponent } from './components/pages/login/login.component';

const routes: Routes = [
    {path: '' , component:LoginComponent},
    {path: 'beszerzes', component:BeszerzesEszkozSelectorComponent}
];

@NgModule({
    imports:[RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
    exports:[RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule{}

and then it talks about how i can use the <router-outlet> tag in the app.html file and that should in this case default for my login component but for me i just get an error message saying router-outlet is not a known element.
So if anyone knows how to solve this it would be much appreciated.

Is this helpful? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44517737/router-outlet-is-not-a-known-element

The BUG you're dealing with usually occurs because Angular doesn't recognize the router-outlet directive. This issue happens when the AppRoutingModule or the routing module containing the RouterModule isn't properly imported into the AppModule.You can solve this issue in the following way.
Ensure the AppRoutingModule is properly import in your AppModule like show below:
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module'; // Import your routing module here 
import { AppComponent } from './app.component'; 
import { LoginComponent } from './components/pages/login/login.component';
import { BeszerzesEszkozSelectorComponent } from './components/pages/beszerzes-eszkoz-selector/beszerzes-eszkoz-selector.component'; 

@NgModule(
{ 
  declarations: [ 
    AppComponent, 
    LoginComponent,
    BeszerzesEszkozSelectorComponent 
  ], 
  imports: [ 
    BrowserModule,
    AppRoutingModule // Make sure this is imported
  ], 
  providers: [], 
  bootstrap: [AppComponent] 
}) 
export class AppModule {}

You can find more about how to configure routing in Angular v16 and lower by following this link
